# mews/captcha on laravel 8,The payload is invalid

Tags: laravel

I'm using mews/captcha package in laravel 8, when something is typed in the captcha filed, this error is returned by laravel:

Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
The payload is invalid.

I did registered the provider and alias as suggested in the documentation and
used the official documentation codes:

```
Route::any('captcha-test', function() {
    if (request()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $rules = ['captcha' => 'required|captcha'];
        $validator = validator()->make(request()->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Incorrect!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: #00ff30;">Matched :)</p>';
        }
    }

    $form = '<form method="post" action="captcha-test">';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '">';
    $form .= '<p>' . captcha_img() . '</p>';
    $form .= '<p><input type="text" name="captcha"></p>';
    $form .= '<p><button type="submit" name="check">Check</button></p>';
    $form .= '</form>';
    return $form;
});
```

Comment: please show what you have written and the localhost link is not needed at all

Comment: I used the documentation example, I think there might be an inconsistency with laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the bug.
encryption should be changed to true in the config.
after running this command:

php artisan vendor:publish

go to this file:
config/captcha.php

and set the excrypt to true

'encrypt' => true,